# Prolog - 'unknown clause' error message when asking for user input when using PIE (Prolog Interface Engine)

Tags: prolog

I'm writing code for a simple program that outputs any phrase that the user inputs. Here's my code so far:

```
input():-
read(X),
nl,
write(X).
```

Here's the output:

```
input().
input().
Unknown clause found read(X$0)
Execution terminated
No solutions
```

Here's my desired output:

```
input().
input().
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: In a comment the OP noted this was originally done using [PIE (Prolog Interface Engine)](http://www.bitwisemag.co.uk/copy/programming/prolog/intro/firststeps.html)

Your problem is that you are using [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) which expects a Prolog term. Prolog terms are not strings that can be of any form, Prolog terms end with a period (`.`). So in your example `input().` works because it ends with a period, `hello` does not work because it does not end with a period.

Using your query

```
?- input().
|: input().
```

and entering `input().` works

```
input()
true.
```

```
?- input().
|: hello
|: .
```

entering `hello` does not work right away as indicated by the second prompt `|:` but then entering the `.` completes the Prolog term and works.

```
hello
true.
```

--

Here is demo of your code, slightly modified running on [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Hangout.swinb).

[image]

---

When I ran your code with [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) installed on my laptop it worked with `input()` as the predicate. When I tried the same with SWISH it complained, but changing the predicate from `input()` to `input` solved that problem.

---

Now knowing that you are not using a common Prolog such as SWI-Prolog and seeing the error message

```
Unknown clause found read(X$0)
```

tells me that PIE does not have `read/1`, I did a quick check of some tutorials for PIE and could not find any use of `read/1`. The obvious conclusion is that PIE does not support `read/1` and if you want to use `read/1` while learning Prolog you will have to use something that does, e.g. SWI-Prolog, SWISH, [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/)

Comment: The thing is: it doesn't allow me to enter an input. When I call the `input()` method, it is supposed to allow me to enter something but when I type `input().` and hit enter, it shows up the unknown clause error message above. I'm running this on PIE (Prolog Interface Engine) if that helps

Comment: If you don't want to download and install Prolog then try [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Hangout.swinb)  - `SWISH: SWI-Prolog for SHaring` It runs in a browser.

Comment: [works like a charm on swish](https://imgur.com/pcVLvME) but [gives me trouble on PIE](https://imgur.com/YTdtQ7u). I guess the issue here is PIE not my code. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: won't let me upvote because I don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: @plantstho I lose more points because of that silly requirement. Thanks. I should send the bill to SO for those.